# php it is possible to return the exact value for my $i

Tags: php

here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$starttime = date("H:i:s");

$targetsfile = $argv[1];
if(!isset($argv[1])) { echo "[-] Try again...\n"; die(); }



$nodes = array();
$nodes = file("$targetsfile", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; pt-pt) AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27";
    $url = $nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do 
{
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
    usleep(5000);
} while($running > 0);

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
    #HERE#
}
echo "DONE!\n";
echo "START TIME: $starttime\n";
$endtime = date("H:i:s");
echo "END TIME: $endtime\n";
?>
```

I try to crawling multiple sites with multi curl function but I need the value for every url which he get the content to can continue to build my script but it return me the value where I write:

```
see #HERE# line
```

There I need the exact value of `$url` for each `$curl_arr[$i]` but if I try there to echo the $curl_arr[$i] value it returns me values like this:

```
Resource id #27Resource id #27Resource id #28Resource id #28DONE!
```

Any chance to return me the exact value of variable $url in my for loop? Or shouild I think another ways to write the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would be possible with [`curl_getinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php):

```php
$url = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Comment: it works, many thanks, I still learning.... i was thinking to build another structure from start to keep tracking the values for eaches variales, but with your solution it was more simple. Thanks.